# How to get file path information from ICompilationUnit?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, filepath

I could get a set of ICompilationUnit using the following code, but I need get the physical file path from the ICompilationUnit or IWorkspaceRoot.

How can I do that?

```
private static Set<ICompilationUnit> getFiles(String projname)   
throws CoreException {
    IWorkspaceRoot ws = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    IProject proj = ws.getProject(projname);
    IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(proj);
    Set<ICompilationUnit> files = new HashSet<ICompilationUnit>();
    javaProject.open(new NullProgressMonitor());
    for (IPackageFragment packFrag : javaProject.getPackageFragments()) {
        for (ICompilationUnit icu : packFrag.getCompilationUnits()) {
            files.add(icu);
        }
    }
    javaProject.close();
    return files;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send the ICompilationUnit the getUnderlyingResource() method.  It returns an IResource that can tell you if it's a file and, if so, what the various forms of its file name and path are.

Note that a null can be returned, too, so watch for that.

something like this:

```
   // resource is an IResource returned by sending 
   // an iCompilationUnit the getUnderlyingResource() method

if (resource.getType() == IResource.FILE) {

    IFile ifile = (IFile) resource;

    String path = ifile.getRawLocation().toString();

}
```

Comment: getType() requires string as a parameter, and getElementType() doesn't work.

Comment: you need to send getType() to the IResource() as above

Comment: As this situation, make sure resource is not null, or will be throw NullPointException.